# Scheduling communication with a slow device

Tags: c, microcontroller, communication

Example C code algorithm

```
while(1)
{
   fun1();
   switch(fun2())
   case 1:  fun3();
   case 2 : fun4();
}

fun1()
{
  command;
  delay 1 sec;
  response;
  if failure, retry;
}
```

Here, fun1, fun2, etc are functions which are similar to each other.
So, the issue is I need to wait 1 sec for response. How can I eliminate the waiting delay?

Comment: The normal way is to poll flags or alternatively use interrupts. Busy-waits aren't used in professional programs.

Comment: Busy waits are routinely used in professional programs.  Consider for example spinlocks in the linux kernel.  At the other end of the scale there are plenty of professionally developed microcontroller products where the processor simply has nothing better to do than spin.  It would be unprofessional to waste time implementing a more complex solution when simply busy waiting is good enough.  Perhaps what you meant is "busy waits aren't used for long periods in complex programs".

Answer (score 0):

You implement multi-threading.

Be it include a [full blown RTOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system), like FreeRTOS or Contiki or MbedOS or [other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_real-time_operating_systems).

Or use a thin layer of scheduling, like [protothread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protothread) or coroutines.

Or reorganize your code and implement in a form of a state-machine in an event-driven system, with scheduling in the form event/timer -> callback. Either using hardware interrupts, or with a custom library to handle the wait-for-event loop, like TimerEvent from MBed or [libevent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libevent) work.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `fun1()` as a state machine that performs a portion of its duties over many invocations.  This example is rough but something like this.

```
typedef enum Status {
   CompletedSuccessfully = 0,
   RetryingDueToError = 1,
   Busy = 2
} Status;

typedef enum State {
   SendCommand = 0,
   Wait = 1,
   CheckResponse = 2,
   Done = 3
} State;


while(1)
{
   Status fun1_status = fun1();
   Status fun2_status = fun2();
   if (fun2_status == CompletedSuccessfully)
   {
      switch(fun2_status)
      case 1:  fun3();
      case 2 : fun4();
   }
}


Status fun1() {
   // state is static so that it retains its value on subsequent invocations.
   static State state = SendCommand;
   Status status = Busy;
  
   switch (state) {
      case SendCommand:
         command;
         state = Wait;
         status = Busy;
         break;

      case Wait:
         if (is time to check response?) {
            state = CheckResponse;
         }
         status = Busy;
         break;

      case CheckResponse:
         response;
         if (failure) {
            status = RetryingDueToError;
            state = SendCommand;
         }
         else {
            status = CompletedSuccessfully;
            state = Done;
         }
         break;

      case Done:
         status = CompletedSuccessfully;
         break;
   }

   return status;
}
```